# Template tags successfully translated but ugettext_lazy() in utils not translating

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I successfully managed to get trans and blocktrans to translate text.

However...

I have a function defined in utils.py  that returns a dictionary containing strings of which some of them I need converted to the current language.
EDIT: *This is a utils.py that I've created in my project directory that are called by views to perform certain auxillary functions on a dict and then return the updated dict

I have done something like this:

```
    try:
     path = default_storage.save(customercode + '/' + file.name, ContentFile(file.read()))
     results['status'] = 'success'
     results['message'] = _(u'Your file has been successfully uploaded')        
    except Exception as e:
     results['status'] = 'error'
     results['message'] = _(u'There was an error uploading your file: ') + str(e)

return results
```

I have also added `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _ to the top of this utils.py file..`

And this "results" dictionary is used in one of my views wherein the whole dictionary after some further processing is passed as a context variable to the template.

I have correctly set the translation in the .po file. All other template tags translate perfectly. Only the above mentioned strings do not translate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I tried the same process in a forms filed label and it translated just fine. It's only the aforementioned areas where it won't translate!

PS: This is my first question on stackoverflow. I apologize in advance if I've made mistakes asking this question.

Comment: You said your results dict is further processed. How does this processing look like? You also said 'all other template tags' do translate. Are you using your results dict inside some template tag?

Comment: Well, some other keys in the results dict are updated or a new key maybe added to it.

And what I meant is.. I am using the values from the results dict in the template tag using the {{ value }} method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I expected,

I was making a very silly mistake. I accessed the incorrect variable in the template while trying to print the translated value! >_<

But I guess one thing I've learnt is staying away from a problem and then coming back to it after a long time helps. You've got to learn the problem again and that sometimes helps you find silly bugs like these!